# ScriptManager disable all mine asp:buttons events

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have and issue like in subject.
I add ScriptManager to my masterpage and everything works fine (for about 1 month) till now. Now it disable mine all events buttons. The page is start loading and nothing happen.
Do you have any idea why this can happen?

Comment: due you have validation on button clicks.if there is no validation write causevalidation=false in button
<asp:Button id="btnsubmit" runat="server" causevalidation="false" />

Comment: i have this on some buttons and on some not and still it is the same issue.